# "Structure needs cleaning" error with Overlay FS

Tags: linux, overlayfs

When I run this command:

```
mount -t overlay overlay -olowerdir=/some_lower_dir_0,upperdir=/some_upper_dir,workdir=/some_work_dir /some/overlay_dir
```

Everything works fine.

When I add more and more lowerdir like so:

```
mount -t overlay overlay -olowerdir=/some_lower_dir_0:/some_lower_dir_1:/some_lower_dir_2,upperdir=/some_upper_dir,workdir=/some_work_dir /some/overlay_dir
```

at some point, when I try to `cd` into `/some/overlay_dir` and run `ls` I get `Structure needs cleaning`.

Is there a size/file limit for overlay?